# Java Null check fails and code proceeds to if statement

Tags: java, string, if-statement, null, tostring

I have an `if` condition within my code and I do not want my code to proceed into the if condition if the value of the variable is `Null` but for some reason, the condition passes and proceeds to the next part but the value of the field is `NULL`.

I am not sure why this issue is happening. A similar approach works for the other fields but not for this field:

```
if (myField != null) {
 System.out.println("WITHIN IF : " + myField);
//prints null
}
```

I researched a bit tried a couple of things like:

```
if(!Objects.isNull(myField))
```

In following cases the condition fails saying that `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)" because the return value of toString() is null`

```
if(myField != null && myField.toString().equals("null"))
```

```
if(myField != null && myField.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
```

I am not understanding what's going wrong here. The value is null but the check fails and it goes within my `If` condition. If I try to convert to `toString()` then it fails saying the value is null.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: It sounds like you `myField` is some kind of object with a `toString()` method that returns null. That's what "the return value of toString() is null" tells you. You should fix the `toString()` method so it doesn't return null.

Comment: What does `myField.toString()` return?
You may also have a misunderstanding of `null`. `null` is not equal to `"null"` (the string).

Comment: @khelwood Thanks a lot for the answer. It's actually enum and it was assigned with `null` so it was failing. Thanks a lot for the explanation it worled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When java calculate value of `"WITHIN IF : " + myField` expression it calls `toString` method on `myField` object.

It could return string `"null"` or it could return actual `null` reference. In both cases you will get `"WITHIN IF : null"` as result.

PS: you have second case at hand.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks a lot for the answer. It's actually enum and it was assigned with `null` so it was failing. Thanks a lot for the explanation it worked.